# Can the word "well" in the phrase "as well as" have its literal meaning "in a good way"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

a sentence from the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 367:
**(1)** *Few if any of them did as well as Kim*.

Does (1) mean (1a) or (1b) or it can mean both?:
**(1a)** *Few if any of them did the same way as Kim*. — (that is, it doesn't say whether Kim did the good way or the bad way)
**(1b)** *Few if any of them did the same **good** way as Kim*.

---

Would adding "it" affect the answer or not?

my sentence:
**(2)** *Few if any of them did **it** as well as Kim*.

Does (2) mean (2a) or (2b) or it can mean both?:
**(2a)** *Few if any of them did **it** the same way as Kim*. — (that is, it doesn't say whether Kim did it the good way or the bad way)
**(2b)** *Few if any of them did **it** the same **good** way as Kim*.

Answer (score 1):

"As well as" in this context is comparing the quality of something.

> This spanner doesn't work as well as that one.

> I didn't cook as well as I did yesterday.

So 1b and 2b are correct in your examples.

"As well as" can also mean "in addition to".

> As well as being a writer, Fred is a pianist

I think the root of this is saying that "Fred plays piano as well as he writes", but that is not how you'd necessarily interpret it idiomatically. Fred might be a very good writer and a mediocre pianist.

If Fred was equally good at both, we'd say:

> Fred plays the piano as well as he writes.

Saying:

> As well as writing, Fred plays the piano.

Just tells us that he does both. (With an implication that writing is more of a focus than playing the piano)

You can also say:

> Fred plays the piano, as well as writing.

This does *not* mean he does them equally well, again it just tells us that he does both.

And you can use "as well as" to mean additionally with no quality implications at all:

> My parents will be there as well as my brother.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly?: if Fred is a good writer and a bad pianist we can say "_Fred plays piano as well as he writes_." meaning he plays piano and also writes.

Comment: No -- see my clarification.

Comment: You said if Fred was equally good at both, we'd say: "_Fred plays the piano as well as he writes_." And if Fred was bad at both, could we also say: "_Fred plays the piano as well as he writes_." ?

Comment: Yes! We could say that, and I'm pretty sure that I have seen that idiom used.

Comment: That is: if the level of playing piano and writing is the same (equally good or equally bad), we can say "_Fred plays the piano as well as he writes._". But if the level is different, we can't say this sentence, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Loviii this expression when somebody does something badly, "as well as" is generally only used for humorous effect. "He writes as well as he cooks... and his cooking is awful!"

Comment: @tgdavies this gives some suggestions about as well meaning in addition https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582933/why-does-the-phrase-as-well-as-mean-in-addition-to

Comment: And if we hear "_Fred plays the piano as well as he writes_.", are we more likely to think it means Fred's level of playing and writing is equally good, equally bad or just equal?

Comment: The author would most likely make it clear from the context around that sentence. I don't think you can assume anything from the sentence in isolation.

Comment: In the 'in addition' sense, we would say "Fred plays the piano as well as writes" without the 'he'; but it would be more idiomatic to say "...as well as being a writer".

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Few if any of them did as well as Kim.

[Well](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well) takes senseA1 and has a similar example here:

> adverb
> A1
> in a **good way**, to a **high or satisfactory standard**:

> **as well as** I can't do it as well as Marie can.

OP's examples (1b) and (2b) are both possible, as tgdavis said.

We can also add **in**:

> Few if any of them did (it) (in) the same good way as Kim.

The [frequencies of usages with and without *it*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+the+same+way%2Cdid+it+the+same+way&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) are as shown in the graphs.